# How to view RAM usage of running parallel program in Ubuntu with command smem?

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing

When running my parallel program with command:

```
smem -k mpiexec ./mandelbrot
```

I see USS, PSS & RSS for other running processes but I don't see my program. How to view RAM usage in this case for program mandelbrot?

Running program:
[image]